# lambda expression join multiple tables ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, lambda

How can I transform this SQL into a lambda expression?

```
SELECT datename(month,eve.EVNfechainicio) AS mes,
       count(eve.EVNid_evento) AS 'Cantidad de Eventos'
FROM pubEVNtEvento AS eve
INNER JOIN pubEMPtEmpresa AS emp ON eve.EMPid_empresa= emp.EMPid_empresa
WHERE emp.EMPnombre='TecnoEventos'
  AND year(eve.EVNfechainicio)= '2016'
GROUP BY datename(month,eve.EVNfechainicio)
```

Comment: Is `datename` and `year` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the lambda Expression should be for the above sql query is

```
db.pubEVNtEvento.Include(i=> i.pubEMPtEmpresa )
        .Where(r => r.pubEMPtEmpresa.EMPnombre=='TecnoEventos' &&
    r.EVNfechainicio=='2016').GroupBy(p=> p.EVNfechainicio).ToList();
```

Here db is the instance of your Entity framework DbContext